# Joining with “while”

Tags: sentence-construction

I have the following ideas:

> Roof outer boundaries are finally connected to the fixed inner bounds
>   by snapping, fixed outer bounds (gutters). And then by allowing a
>   flexible sweeping of other (unfixed) edges framework of closed
>   polygons having their symmetries preserved are created. Later,
>   subsequent successive line intersection leads to closed polygons.

As each idea interacts with the next, I am having trouble linking them.

Here, I have my best try with *while*:

> **While** allowing a flexible sweeping of (outer) unfixed edges, fixed
>   bounds (gutters) are snapped to the fixed inner bounds to
>   construct framework of closed polygons having their preserved
>   symmetries. Successive intersection of adjacent lines are then formed a
>   closed polygon.

Can anyone help me to make a complete sentence which would be accepted in an academic field?

Comment: Please capitalize the first letter of each sentence. The question is hardly readable in it's current form and it can drive people away from answering your question.

Comment: I guess I'd write it as: “While allowing flexible sweeping of the unfixed outer edges, fixed bounds (gutters) are snapped to the fixed inner bounds to construct a framework of closed polygons with their symmetries preserved. Successive intersections of adjacent lines then form a closed polygon.” It's hard to say if that a good way to say it, though, because I have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: You don't seem to have a question about grammar here, or even sentence construction in any general sense. You might try asking about specific words or rules that are difficult for you, or rewriting this in a way that wouldn't require further knowledge of your project to answer but would still be helpful to you.

Comment: I really think you need to express yourself more simply.  Sure, you're writing a technical paper, but you don't get any brownie points for making it hard to understand.  You must first write **clear** sentences; **complicated** can come later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't use "while" there – it makes the sentence hard to understand.

Why? Because, at the beginning of a sentence, *while* can set the reader up for a change in thought. Here's what NOAD says:

> **while** (*conj*.)
>   1 during the time that; at the same time as : *nothing much changed while he was away*.
>   2 whereas (indicating a contrast) : *one person wants out, while the other wants the relationship to continue*.
>   • in spite of the fact that; although : *while I wouldn't recommend a night-time visit, by day the area is full of interest*.

It's that submeaning of Def #2 that gets you into trouble. So, when you write:

> While allowing a flexible sweeping of (outer) unfixed edges...

it's easy to interpret that as:

> In spite of the fact that allowing a flexible sweeping of (outer) unfixed edges...

Unfortunately, your question doesn't elaborate on the nature of the linked thoughts. Is this a step-by-step procedure? Is there some cause and effect going on?  Because of that, I can't give you a definitive answer, but I thought your version with "then" was just fine. You just need to eliminate the leading "and", and add a comma to splice the sentence better:

> *Roof outer boundaries are connected to the fixed inner bounds by snapping, fixed outer bounds (gutters). Then, by allowing a flexible sweeping of other (unfixed) edges, a framework of closed polygons having their symmetries preserved are created. Later, subsequent successive line intersection leads to closed polygons*.

Sorry if I didn't get that right, but the subject matter is a bit specialized.

Comment: The last line is quite true. And truly I don't understand what is the need for joining and making the subject more hard to understand. Anyway +1 for your answer.